# How to show progress bar in each listview item?

Tags: android, android-listview, progress-bar

please help me out to show the progress dialog in listview item.

```
public class DealerSubCatListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Image> Image;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public DealerSubCatListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Image> Image) {

            this.context = context;
            this.Image = Image;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Image.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagesubcat, null);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }

            TextView imagesubcat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagesubcattv);
            // tagLine

            imagesubcat.setText(Image.get(position).image_type);

            return view;
        }

    }
```

So, this is the adapter show the listview item.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [Listview with ProgressBar](https://github.com/mdkess/ProgressBarListView) it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

have a progress bar in `R.layout.imagesubcat` and declare an array of integer for progress

```
int[] progress;
```

in constructor pass the progress array

now in getview

```
progressBar.setProgress(progress[position]);
```

whenever any progress changes just notify adapter

Comment: The problem with this is that when multiple files are being downloaded, a lot of progress updates will be reported, which will produce a lot of calls to notifyDataSetChanged, which has proved to make the buttons not responsible

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to display progress bar in each item of listview ( although seems odd to me), you can declare a progress bar in `R.layout.imagesubcat`

XML tag for progress bar:

```
   <ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

the progress dialog should be shown somewhere you called this Adapter